# log4j 2 JVM usage its own or application one

Tags: log4j2

New version of log4j 2 has been released.  My question when we use log4j 2 in application then JVM used by log4j is its own or the one in which application is running ?

Comment: Of course it doesn't spin up a second JVM. Why do you think it does?

Comment: because there are many third party applications like openDJ (LDAP) which do start their own JVM instance

Comment: Log4j 2 is just a library. OpenDJ includes a server. Totally different types of software.